# Histogram `bins` must increase monotonically matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\pearl\\Downloads\\Age group.csv",
        delimiter=',',
        names=True, dtype=('U7','U40','U13',int))

x= ['15-19','20-24', '25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44']
y = data[data['birth_type'] == 'Single Birth']['total_number_of_mother']

plt.hist(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, I am getting a value error saying `bins` must increase monotonically. May I get some help?

Comment: can you share the dataset?

Comment: `bins` is the second argument in `plt.hist` you use `x` as the first argument and your data as second.

Comment: You probably want to create a bar plot instead of a histogram. `plt.bar(x, y)`

Comment: hi, sorry. i'm really new at this so i don't know how to share the dataset and I will try all the suggestions mentioned. thank you.

Comment: `hist` in essence takes a bunch of numbers (`x`, the first variable) and sorts them in a number of bins (specified by a list of increasing values), then draws a special (different defaults wrt ordinary bar plots) bar plot.  If I understand the nature of your data (judging by the column names) this sorting into bins operation was already done, so you just want to call `plt.bar`, as Johan already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\pearl\\Downloads\\Age group.csv",
delimiter=',',
names=True, dtype=('U7','U40','U13',int))

x= ['15-19','20-24', '25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44']
y = data[data['birth_type'] == 'Single Birth']['total_number_of_mother']

plt.hist([x,y]) # ADD BRACKETS AROUND THIS.
plt.show()
```

The second argument of plt.hist() are the bins, and your code is interpreted as having the bins as "y".