# my box plot has no output in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

this is my code and I don't know what I did wrong. there is no error but when I get my result it doesn't show a boxplot just an x axis and y axis with numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#read in the dataset
data= np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\pearlyn\\Downloads\\education qualification.csv",
        delimiter=',',
        names=True, dtype=('U7','U10','U30','U4',int))
race = data[(data['mother_race']=='INDIAN')]
race_1 = race[race['birth_order']=='1st']
race_2= race_1[race_1['month']== '2019-12']

catA = race_2[race_2['mother_education'] == '"A" LEVEL/DIPLOMA']['birth_count']
catB = race_2[race_2['mother_education'] == '"N" LEVEL/"O" LEVEL']['birth_count']
catC = race_2[race_2['mother_education'] == 'NO QUALIFICATION']['birth_count']
catD = race_2[race_2['mother_education'] == 'PSLE']['birth_count']
catE = race_2[race_2['mother_education'] == 'UNIVERSITY DEGREE']['birth_count']
y_values = np.array([catA, catB, catC, catD, catE])
x_labels = np.unique(data['mother_education'])

plt.boxplot(y_values.transpose(),all(x_labels),patch_artist=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So, in reply to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263726/histogram-bins-must-increase-monotonically-matplotlib), people told you that they can't say much because they don't have your input data. Why do you think this is not relevant here?

Comment: how do i add my input data?

Comment: Please post csv data for a [mcve]. Curious, why are you using `numpy` for this and not `pandas` which is better suited to run logical filters by column identifiers?

Comment: Open your csv data in a text editor and copy/paste sample (enough to reproduce issue) of its contents here, formatted inside a code block. Remember csv is a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is your `data` variable Jupiter notbook is not able fetch that file location from your device because it is online IDE so it can't open your storage location. You should try in on vs code or python's other IDE's because they embedded in system and they can fetch file location.
Please let me if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to reproduce your issue, problem may be due to handling of double quotes within strings that is not supported `numpy.genfromtxt`, particularly with the `mother_education` values. Numpy's text parser doubles the quotes and wraps the entire value in quotes! Therefore, your logical calls return empty arrays since they do not condition to actual values in object array.

See random demonstration below and data print out.

```py
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

educ_groups = ['"A" LEVEL/DIPLOMA', '"N" LEVEL/"O" LEVEL',
               'NO QUALIFICATION', 'PSLE', 'UNIVERSITY DEGREE']

# create random dataset of two columns
np.random.seed(20201212)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({'mother_education': np.random.choice(educ_groups, 500),
                          'birth_count': np.random.randint(1, 15, 500),
                          })
# create csv dataset
csv_data = random_df.to_csv(index=False)

# read in the dataset
data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(csv_data),
                     delimiter=',',
                     names=True, dtype=['U30', int])

print(data[0:25])
# [('"""A"" LEVEL/DIPLOMA"',  6) ('PSLE',  3) ('PSLE',  8)
#  ('UNIVERSITY DEGREE', 13) ('"""N"" LEVEL/""O"" LEVEL"',  3) ('PSLE', 12)
#  ('PSLE',  3) ('UNIVERSITY DEGREE',  9) ('"""N"" LEVEL/""O"" LEVEL"',  9)
#  ('NO QUALIFICATION', 10) ('UNIVERSITY DEGREE',  8)
#  ('UNIVERSITY DEGREE',  5) ('"""N"" LEVEL/""O"" LEVEL"',  7)
#  ('NO QUALIFICATION',  6) ('"""N"" LEVEL/""O"" LEVEL"',  1) ('PSLE', 10)
#  ('NO QUALIFICATION',  8) ('"""N"" LEVEL/""O"" LEVEL"', 13)
#  ('UNIVERSITY DEGREE', 12) ('"""A"" LEVEL/DIPLOMA"',  7)
#  ('NO QUALIFICATION',  7) ('PSLE',  6) ('PSLE',  4)
#  ('NO QUALIFICATION', 10) ('NO QUALIFICATION', 14)]
# [('mother_education', '<U30'), ('birth_count', '<i8')]

print(data.dtype)
# [('mother_education', '<U6'), ('birth_count', '<i8')]
```

#### **Numpy** Fix

A quick fix is to use the rendered numpy values as is in logical calls and then adjust labels to originals. Below also properly labels `x` axis.

```py
catA = data[data['mother_education'] == '"""A"" LEVEL/DIPLOMA"']['birth_count']
catB = data[data['mother_education'] == '"""N"" LEVEL/""O"" LEVEL"']['birth_count']
catC = data[data['mother_education'] == 'NO QUALIFICATION']['birth_count']
catD = data[data['mother_education'] == 'PSLE']['birth_count']
catE = data[data['mother_education'] == 'UNIVERSITY DEGREE']['birth_count']

y_values = np.array([catA, catB, catC, catD, catE], dtype='object')
x_labels = np.unique(['"A" LEVEL/DIPLOMA', '"N" LEVEL/"O" LEVEL',
                      'NO QUALIFICATION', 'PSLE', 'UNIVERSITY DEGREE'])

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.boxplot(y_values.transpose(), labels=x_labels, notch=False, patch_artist=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Numpy Box Plot]

---

#### **Pandas** Plot Build

However, as commented `pandas` may be a better tool especially working with datasets of varying `dtype` such as string categories and number values with grouping aggregation needs. (Numpy works best for n-dimensional data sets of atomic, similar types across all elements. Pandas works best for 2-dimensional data sets of varying types.) Additionally, `pandas.read_csv` properly handles quotes within strings with a range of other [text parsing arguments](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data))   # REPLACE WITH ACTUAL FILE

df.boxplot(column='birth_count', by='mother_education', 
           figsize=(15,5), grid=False, patch_artist=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Pandas oxPlot Output]